# Implementation of runnable with main() method inside. Waste of resources or simply unortodhox?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, memory-management

I received to my mail a piece of code to review. This code will be used in a Web Service and it's java.

I was surprised when I found that the class owning the main() methods implements Runnable, and  is used to intialize threads to be run in this mail method.

This means that we will be initializing many objects with a main() method never to be called. Despite it's of course allowed, it's highly unortodhox for mixing business logic with the main routine. This brought me a question: As we create many objects containing a main() method. Are we wasting memory resources? (apart of how ugly this can be). I'm implicitly questioning on memory waste if objects are instantiated with methods never to be used. I couldn't find a satisactory answer elsewhere.

Comment: Neither. No identifiable resource is being wasted, and there is nothing unorthodox about it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you determined that it's "highly unorthodox", unless you're the Pope of the Java Church. But it's definitely not a waste of resources.

The code for methods is not duplicated for each instance, as you seem to think. It exists one single time and the instances share it. If you can't afford the resources for a single method that's never called, you're running one tight ship.

I.e. it might not be the prettiest solution, but it's not that big of a problem you're making it out to be.

Comment: That was my thinking, and what I wanted to confirm. Can you provide any source? 

In terms of extensibility IT IS a problem, unless you prefer to code in Java as in BASIC with no OO patterns at all.

Comment: I can't make head or tail of your last sentence. Regarding your first sentence, 'unorthodox' is your assertion: it is up to you to support it; and the fact that methods aren't duplicated per instance is as per the JVM Specification. Frankly I  expect any Java or OO programmer to already know both the fact and the source.

Comment: This is preposterous. You asked for a source. Presumably so you could read it. I provided it. In a comment.